# What are the difference between part-r-00000 and part-m-00000 files in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

We are working with BigData while using Hadoop my Virtual Box running CentOS. whenever we perform some programs it creates 2 different files 1) part-r-00000 and 2) part-m-00000. so what are the difference and pupose of that two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are files produced by MapReduce jobs. `r` means the file has been output by a Reducer, `m` means the file has been output by a Mapper.

Answer (score 3):

The output files are by default named `part-x-yyyyy`

where:

1) `x` is either `‘m’` or `‘r`’, depending on whether the job was a **map** only job, or **reduce**

2) `yyyyy` is the Mapper, or Reducer **task number** (zero based`(00000`))

So if a job which has 10 reducers, files generated will have named `part-r-0000`0 to `part-r-0000`9, one for each reducer task.

It is possible to change the default name.

This is all you need to do in the Driver class to change the default of the output file:
`job.getConfiguration().set(“mapreduce.output.basename”, “Neo”)`;

So this will result in your files being called `“Neo-r-00000”`.